# Pushing an object within its key in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 with Firebase 3 and I have a read method that returns a JSON with keys and values, this is part of the structure

```
{
 "1475323200" : {
   "-KfNUUZf9ehNdVSCiBO": {
    "date": 1489690818,
    "msg": "Mussum Ipsum",
    "title": "Pagamentos"
   }
 },
 "1478001600": {
   "-KfNUUZf9ehNdVSCiBO": {
    "date": 1489690818,
    "msg": "Mussum Ipsum",
    "title": "Pagamentos"
   }
  }
}
```

and this is the code I have now or what I'm trying to do. I'll explain after it

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
    firebase.database().ref('Administrative/Informs').on('value', snap => {
        if (snap.val() != null) {
            let data = snap.val(); //will be an object
            this.organizer(data).then(res => {
                console.log(this.informs);
            })
        } else {
            this.noInforms == true;
        }
    });
}

organizer = (data: any): Promise<boolean> => {
    for (var i = Object.keys(data).length; i > 0; i--) {
        this.informs.push(data[i]);
    }

    return new Promise<boolean>(res => {
        res(true);
    })
}
```

The 'value' query on firebase returns me the keys in ascending format, but the keys later'll be used with momentJS to separate the informatives by month, but I have to use then in descending format so it goes from the actual month to the latest saved, now it's `2016/dec > 2017/jan > 2017/feb > ...` and I need `2017/mar > 2017/feb > 2017/jan > ...`

I tried this ways to accomplish this:

- Using `this.informs = Object.keys(snap.val()).reverse();` | it only saves the keys and more 6 or 7 undefined fields
- Using for inside for, like `for(key in snap.val()){ this.informs.push(key)}`and inside other for pushing all values inside a new object and then attributing it like `this.informs[key] = values;`
- Pushing objects inside `this.informs[key]`.
- Getting values with `child_added`, but it returns me every child without the key i'll use to get the month.

So, how can I save the same object in an array but reversed by the first keys? Sine i'll use it in a *ngFor i need it to be an array with a length parameter.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Is data (the dados sent to this.organiser, is it an array or an object? Since it doesn't makse sense to me to use `Object.keys().length`, a number and then use `data[i]` So if data is an array, why use Object.keys? If data is an object, do you mean using `data[ Object.keys(data)[i] ]` to select the record? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Shilly oh, i'm sorry, since my code is not in english i've decided to translate it so i'ts better for people to understand. Will update code

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` will create an array of the object's key in an arbitrary order. If you want to sort those keys you can do something like this:

```js
var data = {
 "1475323200" : {
   "-KfNUUZf9ehNdVSCiBO": {
    "date": 1489690818,
    "msg": "Mussum Ipsum",
    "title": "Pagamentos"
   }
 },
 "1478001600": {
   "-KfNUUZf9ehNdVSCiBO": {
    "date": 1489690818,
    "msg": "Mussum Ipsum",
    "title": "Pagamentos"
   }
  }
}

window.informs = [];
Object.keys(data).sort((a,b) => {parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)}).forEach(k => this.informs.push(data[k]))
console.log(informs);
```

`.sort((a,b) => {parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)})` will sort the keys in ascending order, for descending order use `.sort((a,b) => {parseInt(b) - parseInt(a)})`